Converting Add-in file in ModelBuilder or ArcPy from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro
We have an ArcMap Add-in file and we would like to open it, to see how it works to convert it to ArcGIS Pro.

Not all add-ins are compiled code.  ArcMap also has Python add-ins.  If your .addin file is a Python add-in, you can unzip the .addin file (you may need to rename to .zip depending on your zip software) to see the Python code.
However note that Python add-ins are not and will not be supported in ArcGIS Pro. So if you do have a Python add-in and access its code, you'll neeed to convert the logic to a geoprocessing tool or port it to the ArcGIS Pro SDK for .NET.

ok. we are going to analyse add-in. I believe is VB. yes, it's not possible to importo to arcgisPRO, unfortunately 1 Thank you very much

You cannot do that because it is compiled code. You can open them with say Zip7 but what you'll find is the DLL. That would have been compiled down from VB or c#. You need to approach the developer(s). They will have the source code most likely in a Visual Studio project.

we'll going to try that approach that you sugested. I doubt they will give us but thank you very much for your answer.
